# launchd service execute bash command on Mac

Tags: launchd

I am trying to start a service on my Mac.  This service needs to execute a bash script.

I have the following:

**watcher.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Watcher service - used to copy error logs

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=watcher.sh
```

In the same directory I have:

**watcher.sh**

```
# File to output to
ErrorLogFile="./error.log"
# File to read from
ExampleLogFile="./example.log"


if [ ! -e "$ErrorLogFile" ]; then   # check if file exists
    echo "Creating error file $ErrorLogFile"
    touch $ErrorLogFile
fi

echo "copying error messages from $ExampleLogFile to $ErrorLogFile"
# copy from one file to the other
while :; do grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile > $ErrorLogFile; sleep 2; done

echo "done"
```

From the terminal, I go to the same directory, and run:

```
sudo launchctl start watcher
```

Nothing happens.

If I run the following from the terminal:

```
sudo watcher.sh
```

It works as expected (i.e. the `echo` is printed to the terminal and the lines are copied to the file.

I think the problem is that the `ExecStart` in the service is not executing the `watcher.sh` script.

**Question**

How can I get the service to execute the bash script?

Comment: provide full path like so `ExecStart=full_path_to_watcher.sh`

Comment: @Krishna, thanks, but my issue is that this script needs to run on a different server, and I don't know what its directory structure is. That's the reason I put the `.sh` and `.server` in the same directory.  Doesn't this mean I do not have to specify a path?

Comment: You have systemd on a Mac?

Comment: @Rob, nope. I don't think Mac supports systemd? It does have launchd which I am trying to test with.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411501/can-i-install-systemctl-onto-my-mac

Comment: But you have this tagged as systemd

Comment: @Rob, my mistake. I will change it